# Run wiki.js behind a corporate proxy (no configuration in wiki.js possible)

Tags: centos, proxy

I would like to run wiki.js, which is a node.js program, behind a proxy.

Apparently, wiki.js does not have config for using proxies.

Is there any way to give wiki.js Internet access?

I am running this on CentOs 7.6.

Comment: Huh? Does it even need to connect to the Internet?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Following the documentation, it should be possible to download the localization manually. But was not able to make that work. Furthermore, it throws errors in the log (for not being able to download files from the internet) and on the UI (unspecific).

Comment: It looks like you can [sideload](https://docs.requarks.io/install/sideload) but it only works if you have declared [offline mode](https://docs.requarks.io/install/config#offline-mode). I would also suggest you contact the developers and ask for proxy support to be added.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you very much, I missed the `offline` parameter. There is already a request for proxy support, and I really hope that this will be implemented soon. I guess many people inside large companies share the same problem.

Comment: It's so easy to use a proxy in Node.js code that I'm surprised they didn't already do it.

Comment: But I probably cannot set a proxy on Node.js level that would be automatically used by wiki.js?

Comment: It's just a programming framework. The code would have to be written to do that. It's easy, but they didn't do it.

Comment: Please take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64728579/8800627). It is dockerized solution for your problem.